# PS - compare WMI query for docking station version to specific value

Tags: powershell, compare, wmi

Trying to figure out how to compare the returned value of a WMI query to a set value.
I.e.
`Get-WmiObject -class HP_DockAccessory -computername $_ -namespace root/HP/InstrumentedServices/v1 | Select FirmwarePackageVersion`
and compare it to the current available version of 1.18 (hard set in the script).

I'll further wrap this into an existing script that will prompt to pull down the firmware updater if the version is below the 1.18.

when I try and compare values in PS, I keep getting an error about objects not being the same type.
Any pointers people can offer?
Thanks

Comment: We need more info, whats the full error message? whats the output of that command, since we cant replicate without that dock.

Comment: In addition to the exact error message text, what type is the ```FirmwarePackageVersion``` property?  (assign it to a variable and write out the type info... ```$version = Get-WmiObject ... | Select FirmwarePackageVersion; write-host $version.GetType().FullName``` and can you also include the code that "hard set"s the available version variable *and* show how you compare it. All of that info should be trivially cut&pasteable from your system, but impossible for us to guess from your question as it currently stands...